# Is it a good idea to store a sync.WaitGroup inside a Context in go?

Tags: go, asynchronous

I need to wait for some nested go go routine calls to finish and currently passing a sync.WaitGroup along the call stack.

Since I already have a context in every signature I'm thinking about just adding the wait group to the context.

Could look like this:

```
func TestWaitGroupInContext(t *testing.T) {
    res := make(chan int, 3)

    sendNumber := func(ctx context.Context, i int) {
        wg := ctx.Value("wg").(*sync.WaitGroup)
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(20 * time.Millisecond)
        res <- i
    }

    doStuff := func(ctx context.Context) {
        wg := ctx.Value("wg").(*sync.WaitGroup)

        wg.Add(3)
        go sendNumber(ctx, 1)
        go sendNumber(ctx, 2)
        go sendNumber(ctx, 3)

    }

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "wg", &wg)
    doStuff(ctx)

    assert.Equal(t, 0, len(res))
    wg.Wait()
    assert.Equal(t, 3, len(res))

}
```

Any thoughts why this could be a bad idea?

Comment: From software design perspective I'd prefer an implementation when `doStuff` does not know about "global" synchronisation but instead creates its own instance of a `wg` and returns it. Then it's an its caller responsibility to decide how to orchestrate interactions of different pieces of the application.

Comment: eg: `sendNumber` does not even need to cooperate, as long as `doStuff` does everything on its side: `go func() { 
sendNumber(ctx, 1);
wg.Done();
}()` If it's done this way - then `sendNumber` is a trivial 2 lines function.

Answer (score 2):

Context is to store request-specific information. It is not a good place to store something like a waitgroup. However, there are no rules against it either.

In the example you gave, you can simply declare the waitgroup in the enclosing scope, and make it available to all goroutines without passing it as a separate argument.

Generally, you don't have to pass the waitgroup to the goroutines as arguments. You can always do:

```
wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
ctx:=context.Background()

wg.Add(1)
go func() {
   defer wg.Done()
   doStuff(ctx)
}()
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
   defer wg.Done()
   doOtherStuff(ctx)
}()
```

If passing a waitgroup is not possible like this, it is best to pass it explicitly.

Comment: It's not possible with a deeper callstack where the go routines do not share the same wg closure but rather the the wg passed through arguments. That's the case in my application. Still there are cases (e.g. in tests) where I need to wait for everything to be finished.

Comment: "is to store request-specific information" --- OP didn't even mention they have an http server. `Context` is just a data structure that is to be used for _anything you want_.

Comment: @zerkms, "request" does not have to be an HTTP server. This is from context doc:  "... which carries deadlines, cancellation signals, and other request-scoped values across API boundaries and between processes."

Comment: Well yes, actually I have CoAP requests, sometimes also HTTP. But all methods that get a context do not really care about the origin of the context. I also have a context that wraps the lifetime of my application and contexts that wraps calls to external services and need a deadline, etc. there are many reasons to use a context.

Comment: @Tarion, IMHO, it is best to keep it explicit and pass it as an argument.

Comment: @BurakSerdar "which carries deadlines, cancellation signals" ... and WaitGroup is kind of the opposite of a cancellation signal. It's a "I'm finished" signal. That why I consider it to be in the context :)

Comment: @Tarion go documentation tries to be helpful for beginners to provide examples on how a data structure _might_ be used. And then see the community appeals to those examples as _the only right way_ to do it. It's a "go way" to only do what famous people or a Go blog says :shrug:

Comment: @Tarion, there are no hard rules about this. "It rubs me the wrong way" is the best advice I can offer. If you like it, use it. I'd pass it around explicitly.

Comment: @Tarion Waitgroup, like other concurrency primitives, requires precise, careful use to ensure the intended effect.  Parameters are a more robust way to pass data because they are type-safe, semantically traceable, and guaranteed to exist. Context values share none of these properties, making them far more brittle.